# Plone 4.1 -> 4.2, Ubuntu 10.10, stuck on buildout version error

Tags: plone, upgrade

started with 4.0.1

in buildout.cfg

```
  extends = 
    base.cfg 
#     versions.cfg 
#     http://dist.plone.org/release/4.1-latest/versions.cfg
    http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2-latest/versions.cfg
```

4.0 -> 4.1 went fine
4.1 -> 4.2 gives zc.buildout version error I haven't figured out

```
bin/buildout

    Error: There is a version conflict.
    We already have: zc.buildout 1.4.4
    but zc.recipe.egg 1.3.2 requires 'zc.buildout>=1.5.0'
```

http://buildoutcoredev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/issues.html
seems to suggest remedies:
"To fix, you have a couple options. First, you can force buildout to run with the version you already have installed by invoking the version tag. This tells your [Plone] bootstrap.py file to play nicely with the version that you already have installed."

In my case that would be

> python bootstrap.py --version=1.4.4

However this doesn't help, same error as before,
the other suggestion, deleting the zc.buildout egg,
fails hard.

Suggestions?

Thanks,
Kent

Answer (score 0):

That way will not work as `zc.recipe.egg` 1.3.2 requires `zc.buildout` 1.5+.

You can try to *downgrade* `zc.buildout.egg` to an older version (a version that do not require so recent `zc.buildout`, give it a try) or *upgrade* `zc.buildout`.

I suggest you to upgrade your zc.buildout, pinning a modern version:

```
[buildout]
...
[versions]
...
zc.buildout = 2.4.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try them.

Comment: @ktenney: Did it work? You might also want to have look at https://github.com/collective/minimalplone4. Installing buildout in a virtual enviroment and pinning setuptools and zc.buildout has always worked for me, in different setups, so far. Thanks to Johannes Raggam&Co. for providing and sharing this useful starter-point for newbies!

Comment: No, I couldn't get it working. AFAICT I'm being thwarted by the 10.10 ubuntu version, unable to get required system packages. Next time I tackle it I'll look at minimalplone4.

Thanks,
Kent

Comment: @ktenney: This is what I used back then with Ubu-10: `apt-get install g++ zlibc python-imaging zlib1g-dev python-dev build-essential`, HTH.

Comment: @ktenney: FWIW, for Ubu-11 it was: `apt-get install build-essentials g++ g++-4.2 zlibc python-imaging zlib1g-dev python-dev`